# Problem after installing CBL Mariner on bare metal server while login

Tags: operating-system

I was trying to install the CBL-Mariner 2.0 OS on a bare metal DELL server. Steps followed are below;

Step 1: Download the ISO image from the " **https://aka.ms/mariner-2.0-x86_64-iso** ".

Step 2: Create a bootable USB device and connect it to the server.

Step 3: Boot the server using the OS.

Step 4: Installation (Graphic based) is successful. While installation, it asked for the device name, user name and password. I put those accordingly.

Step 5. Reboot the server and once it ask for the login as root (please note, i am still accessing for console), i am using the same password which I configured while installation.

I am not able to login. Am I making some mistake here?

I see some default password of CBL Mariner as p@ssw0rd, i tried that also for root login.
I changed the keyboard to ensure, the keystrokes are not causing the issue. No luck.

Any suggestion please.